# Getting a typeError: Expected 3 arguments, got 4

Tags: python

This is the error I'm getting:

```
       records[recordCount]= newRecord._make(line)
       File "<string>", line 21, in _make
       TypeError: Expected 3 arguments, got 4
```

This is the code:

```
      for line in database:
          records[recordCount]= newRecord._make(line)
          recordCount=recordCount+ 1
```

New to python so I don't know what I am doing wrong.I can't tell where the mistake is.

Comment: What does this `_make`  function look like?

Comment: this line here tells you where you should be looking: `File "<string>", line 21, in _make`. In some file object `"<string>"`, on line 21 of the function `_make`

Comment: Thank you. Got it sort it now.The actual program was that in the file that it was reading there were 4 columns instead of the 3 that I mentioned earlier in a namedtuple.